# Building interference graph for register allocation

Tags: compiler-construction, register-allocation

How can I build an interference graph so I may use it in register allocation? How do I determine live ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Live ranges are usually detected with liveness analysis for basic blocks. Liveness analysis can be computed using dominance frontiers.

[A Simple, Fast Dominance Algorithm](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~keith/EMBED/dom.pdf) is a good read. I implemented both dominance and liveness analysis for a code analysis framework. You may have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/source/browse/deprecated/java/Apparat.Core/src/com/joa_ebert/apparat/controlflow/utils/Dominance.java?name=with-deprecated-source) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/source/browse/deprecated/java/Apparat.Core/src/com/joa_ebert/apparat/taas/toolkit/livenessAnalysis/LivenessAnalysis.java?name=with-deprecated-source).